# Quotes appearing as "?" in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, fonts, xetex, overleaf, greek

I'm using Overleaf's XeLaTeX compiler, along with \usepackage{polyglossia} to write greek and latin text. There seems to be some conflict between polyglossia and my bibliography: [image]

I've tried different lines of \usepackage[xx]{csquotes} trying to fix this, but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.You've not shown us your source, but my wild guess is that you copy/pasted your quotes into Overleaf, and they got pasted in as tilted "smart quotes".  Try deleting them and retyping.  You want to use backtick (up near escape?) for opening quotes, and apostrophe (over near enter?) for closing quotes.

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm including code into my .bib file from google scholar. There are no quotes in the citing code provided by google scholar. Rewritting the text between the  '?' does't fix anything. I'm using \cite{} to citate so I don't use any quotes myself.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix your problem.  If you move your solution into an Answer box, then you'll be able (in a day or two?) mark the problem as solved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!